# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') at get videoArticle [as videoArticle]

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been searching up for solutions but I cannot find the right answer to fix this code.

The error says: AppComponent.html:15 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') at get videoArticle [as videoArticle]

and this is my code

```
get videoArticle() {
    return this.results.filter((val) => val.type === ArticleType.VIDEO);
  }
```

html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="videoArticle.length">
      <article-renderer-component [articles]="videoArticle"></article-renderer-component>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: How do you set value to results? I assume that you send a request and the response gets delayed.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I removed the delay here in return of(articles).pipe(); and everything went well.